# How to reset state of sort direction image (triangle) in a grid panel header in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

There is a grid panel. After some user actions (like going to another grid page or applying filters to the grid column or changing sorting order in some column (sorting are remote in my case)) request is submitted to a server and it returns an appropriate result.
But in some cases i need to get a confirmation from the user to proceed a request.

It was found out that the most convenient way to interrupt request submitting and to show to user a confirmation message is to catch a store's 'beforeload' event and return 'false' if user say no

So, an issue is described below.
There is our initial state (see sorting direction):
[image]

then user changes the sorting order on this column, request is about to being submitted to a server but the user get a confirmation message, say 'no' and request is aborted. So data in the grid are not changed (and it's correct) but image in header changes to another direction
[image]

Well, is there a way to return 'triangle sorting' image to correct state?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var headerEl = grid.headerCt.items.get(colIndex).el;
el.removeCls('x-column-header-sort-ASC')
el.addCls('x-column-header-sort-DESC')
```

Comment: eventually i have found some variants based on your solution but there is one more issue unfortunately. Applying styles changes 'triangle' image in the right way but a grid itself has kind of (i don't know how to say) state. what does it mean? for instance default sorting in a column is ASC, user clicks to sort in DESC order, then the user say 'no' on confirmation dialog and the 'triangle' image will be look like 'ASC' and that's ok. but if user clicks on DESC sorting again then nothing happens because the grid is kind of in 'DESC state' already. it remember that DESC was clicked a moment ago

Answer (score 0):

so, complete solution which works fine for me is:

1. preparative step: to store somewhere all state that you need (in my case column and sorting order)
2. to change CSS as @kevhender has suggested
3. invoke `'your_grid_panel'.headerCt.clearOtherSortStates('saved_column')`. because user may click any column you have to clear all except your 'saved_column'
4. to do `'saved_column'.sortState = 'saved_sorting_order'`. it allows to avoid the issue i've described in the comment to the previous answer.